# Rails: If param equals a value syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to check if a param equals a value with this if statement in the view:

```
<% if param[:knowsifemployermatches] == "Yes" %>show<% end %>
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `param' for #<#<Class:0x000001070d2688>:0x00000103a8cf88>
```

Comment: its **params[:kn...]** not **param[:kn...]**

Comment: It's `params` instead of `param`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `params` instead of `param`

```
<% if params[:knowsifemployermatches] == "Yes" %>show<% end %>
```

Comment: Works for me. thank you!